# Moderator Nominations - Nominate Another User

Tags: discussion, election

In the moderator elections, is it possible to nominate another user?

I only see how to nominate yourself.

Comment: Yes: Go to their house and shout at them until they nominate themselves. I think the idea is that people have to want to be nominated. :)

Comment: Lol, OK thanks.

Comment: Although there has been a precedent where the person was away: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/467/1529

Comment: Mechanically? No, it is not possible to nominate another user, and ali's answer covers that part. However, if you think a certain user may be a viable candidate, it's quite fine to tell them they have your support in, say, chat.

Comment: I definitely think there should be a way to nominate someone, but they have the option to decline, such as a setting in their profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are three phases:

1.Nomination

> In the nomination phase, any community member in good standing with
>   more than 300 reputation may **nominate themselves** to be a community
>   moderator.
>
> Nominees are required to construct a small, freely editable
>   introduction to describe why they might make a good community
>   moderator. Comments are active during the length of the nomination
>   phase – please comment freely, particularly if there is any way a
>   nominee introduction can be improved or refined to be more clear.
>
> All nominees are displayed in most recently nominated first order.
>
> Nominations are not binding; nominees may withdraw at their discretion
>   at any point during the nomination phase.
>
> After 7 days, the top 30 nominees, ordered by reputation, advance to
>   the primary phase. However, if there are 10 candidates or less, we
>   skip directly to the election phase.

2.Primary

> In the primary phase, all nominees advance to preliminary community
>   voting. Any community member with 150 reputation may vote in the
>   primary.
>
> There is no commenting in this phase, only one up or down vote per
>   candidate. The candidate vote scores are all public. Initial voting
>   should provide a rough sense of which candidates are most electable.
>
> All candidates are displayed in random order.
>
> The primary is not binding; nominees may withdraw at their discretion
>   at any point during the nomination phase.
>
> After 4 days, the top 10 candidates based on primary vote score
>   proceed onward to the election phase.

3.Election

> In the election phase, up to 10 candidates advance to final community
>   voting. Any community member with 150 reputation may vote in the
>   election.
>
> Each community member has 3 votes. Please cast your votes in order of
>   preference, starting with the most desirable candidate first.
>
> All candidates are displayed in random order.
>
> The vote tallies are private until the election is complete.
>
> After 4 days, the final voting results will be freely downloadable
>   from this page forever, and we will calculate the winners using
>   OpenSTV with the Meek STV method.

so the point I think is to nominate yourself, what if a user doesn't want to be nominated but gets a good result so gets put forward but doesn't commit? So I guess nominating yourself is the best solution as it would show you want the position and will spend the time as a mod because you want to :)